# OpenVPN work in China

Tags: amazon-ec2, openvpn

Next week, I'm going to China to work, and I'm worried about the connections there. To prevent this, I installed and configured OpenVPN on an EC2 instance in AWS. I'm navigating it right now.
My EC2 is in Virginia and my traffic is masked in California.
Does this mean I can access my gmail, whatsapp, google and etc ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my personal experience, yes it works and you can access whatever you want if you are routing 0.0.0.0/0 through your VPN.

My company uses OpenVPN extensively and from our experience, **you can connect OpenVPN from China but you cannot connect OpenVPN to China**.

To illustrate this more clearly -

1. OpenVPN server in UK, client connects from Shanghai, works perfectly fine.
2. OpenVPN server in Beijing, client connects from US, cannot connect.

And we have OpenVPN servers in UK, US, HK, SG to confirm this behaviour, which is really weird. I do not understand why the authority would block inbound connection but not outbound one, but that is just how it is.

However if you have the time I would suggest setting up **shadowsocks VPN** which seems to be the best VPN to bypass detection these days.